# MacOS Music "now playing" displays title; not work/movement

Tags: music

I have edited meta-data on my Mac to flip a number of classical tracks to work/movement style. This change has synced to iCloud because I see the tracks listed in that style on my phone afterwards. However, in at least two places, the Mac player is still showing just the titles, which are still stored in the metadata. (The two places are the now-playing strip on top of the app, and also in the listing of history/future tracks that you can slide over from the right.)

Is there any way to force these displays to use the work/movement info instead?